# mistake in query or by post method

Tags: php, sql

I am getting result with **$id='S%'**,  but not with **$id = $id.'%'** when recieved **$id = 's'** by post

```
$id = $_POST['user_data'];
if($_POST['user_data'].lenght<2)
   { 

       $query = "SELECT id, oauth_provider, first_name, last_name, email, phone, STATUS , picture, link, createdFROM users WHERE first_name LIKE ? ORDER BY id DESC " ;
       $id = $id.'%';
       echo ''.$id; 
         $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
         $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
         $stmt->execute();
          $result = $stmt->get_result();
          echo $result->num_rows;
   }
```

ialready recieved $id= s by post also checked it by echo it.
output when id= **$id='S%'** : 
 9
output when id= **$id=$id.'%'** : 
 0

Comment: `createdFROM` you have an error here, did you notice?

Answer (score -1):

Your query seems to be wrong, it should be

$query = "SELECT id, oauth_provider, first_name, last_name, email, phone, STATUS , picture, link, created FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE ? ORDER BY id DESC " ;

and here is a workaround

`$variable = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$query = "SELECT id, oauth_provider, first_name, last_name, email, phone, STATUS , picture, link, created FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE '% $variable' ORDER BY id DESC";`